# Wordpress Sidebar display issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have made the sidebar sticky by using fixed sidebar plugin but the sidebar disappear when scroll back to top I have tried many other plugin but they're not working. This
https://willowdaleequity.com/blog/acquire-69-unit-georgia-apartment-complex-press-release/
is the url of the website on which I'm facing the issue.

Please help me with this problem. I'm using Hub theme by Liquid Themes on my website.

I've also tried following custom css code instead of any plugin but it's also not working.
`position: sticky; top:100px; bottom: 100px;`

Comment: can you deactivate your plugin for a while?

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin is addding position relative when scrolling to top, is there any option in your plugin to change position if on top

add this css and it will show

figure.wp-block-image.size-full.is-style-default.my-sidebar.FixedWidget__fixed_widget {
position: initial !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

Just apply below CSS and you issue will be solved.

**CSS Code:**
figure.wp-block-image.size-full.is-style-default.my-sidebar.FixedWidget__fixed_widget:not([style*="position: fixed"]) {
position: initial !important;
}

If you still find issue please let me know
Thanks